# How do we use the input:focus selector in angular 2+ component?

Tags: css, angular, input, focus

I have a form that contains something like the following:

```
<div class="form-field">
<input-component [tabIndex]="tabData.tabEnable"></input-component>
</div>
<div class="form-field">
<input [tabIndex]="tabData.tabEnable" matInput cgiPrecision type="number"/>
</div>
```

In the css I have this:

```
input:focus {
border: $border-width solid $darkblue
}
```

but the border only shows on the **input** element and not the **input-component** component which has an **input** wrapped inside of it. How can I get the input:focus to work for the custom angular component as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom component should listen for the `focus` event, then focus the input.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input',
  template: `<input #myInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="innerValue">`,
  styles: [`
    input {border: 5px solid green; } 
    input:focus { border: 5px solid blue; }
  `]
})
export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor  {

  @ViewChild('myInput', {static: false}) inputCtrl;

  //...functions to implement ControlValueAccessor

  @HostListener('focus')
  focusHandler() {
   this.inputCtrl.nativeElement.focus();
 }
}
```

[Here's a stackblitz demonstrating.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5dygat?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-input.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

scss files are limited to their angular component. If you want to use css globally, use the `style.scss`.

Another option is, integrate the scss into your child component with the `style-urls` array:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'input-component',
  templateUrl: '/input-component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './input-component.scss',             // own scss file
    './../path-to-other-compontent.scss'  // <--- here
  ]
})
export class InputComponent {
  [...]
}
```